# Troubleshooting Ineffective Port-Level Value Changes in Kernel Bond Code

Tags: debugging, port, bond

I'm engaged in configuring bond settings within the Linux kernel environment and encountering an issue regarding the modification of port-level values through the ad_user_port_key file in the SysFS interface. Despite attempting to alter these settings, I'm observing that the changes fail to reflect in the output log when inspecting via sudo cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0.

Could you please provide guidance on resolving this discrepancy?

I tried `sudo ip link set bond0 type bond ad_user_port_key` this command to change the values in port level. But it is not reflecting.

```
Slave Interface: enp0s8
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 08:00:27:76:e5:b8
Slave queue ID: 0
Aggregator ID: 1
Actor Churn State: monitoring
Partner Churn State: monitoring
Actor Churned Count: 0
Partner Churned Count: 0
details actor lacp pdu:
    system priority: 547
    system mac address: 08:00:27:56:e7:b9
    port key: 9
    port priority: 255
    port number: 2
    port state: 61
details partner lacp pdu:
    system priority: 545
    system mac address: 06:00:27:67:e5:85
    oper key: 9
    port priority: 255
    port number: 2
    port state: 63
```

Not only this value, any of the port level value changes are not reflecting in the output.

I tried to change it in SysFS file as well "/sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/". That change also not reflecting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic]. SO is only for _programming_ questions. You might have better luck on [su] or [unix.se].